# PHP MySQL: decrypt a column value from a MySQL row that was encrypted upon insertion and parse to JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json, encryption

Everything is working, all I want is to decrypt the db column containing the credit card number from the database with the following example:

```
$decp = $crypt->decrypt($encp);
```

the row in question is:

```
'Number' => $row['cardNumber'],
```

the entire code is:

```
// get the cards
$jsonresult = $conn->query("SELECT nameOnCard, cardNumber, cardType, cardDate, ccvCode
                                FROM cy_user_credit_cards
                                WHERE accountNumber='$accountNumber'");
$creditCard = [];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($jsonresult)) {
    array_push($creditCard, [
        'Name'   => $row['nameOnCard'],
        'Number' => $row['cardNumber'],
        'Type' => $row['cardType'],
        'Date' => $row['cardDate'],
        'ccv' => $row['ccvCode']
    ]);
}

    // Convert the Array to a JSON String and echo it
    $ccJSON = json_encode($creditCard);
    echo $ccJSON;
$conn->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you would want to do something like this:

```
// get the cards
$jsonresult = $conn->query("SELECT nameOnCard, cardNumber, cardType, cardDate, ccvCode
                                FROM cy_user_credit_cards
                                WHERE accountNumber='$accountNumber'");
$creditCard = [];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($jsonresult)) {
    array_push($creditCard, [
        'Name'   => $row['nameOnCard'],
        'Number' => $crypt->decrypt($row['cardNumber']),
        'Type' => $row['cardType'],
        'Date' => $row['cardDate'],
        'ccv' => $row['ccvCode']
    ]);
}

    // Convert the Array to a JSON String and echo it
    $ccJSON = json_encode($creditCard);
    echo $ccJSON;
$conn->close();
```

Keep in mind, You really do not want to store all of these credit card details in your database if it is not absolutely necessary. I would urge you to look elsewhere to handle credit card payments.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I already tried that, for some reason, it's not working.

Comment: The echo $ccJSON statement at the end doesn't even work?

Comment: Not at at all @Nitsew

Comment: Replace `echo $ccJSON;` with `var_dump($ccJSON);` and tell me what you get.

Comment: There might be an issue with database query. Try doing `var_dump(mysqli_fetch_assoc($jsonresult));`

Answer (score 0):

You can decrypt the string upon pushing your data into the array like so:

```
array_push($creditCard, [
    'Name'   => $row['nameOnCard'],
    'Number' => $crypt->decrypt($row['cardNumber']),
    'Type' => $row['cardType'],
    'Date' => $row['cardDate'],
    'ccv' => $row['ccvCode']
]);
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I already tried that, it's not working.

Comment: I think you should mention how you encrypted the data. if you're trying to decrypt a column using `decrypt()` this column but you encrypted it using per se, `md5()`, it wont definitely work. Can you add the loc where you encrypted it before inserting it inside the database?

Comment: Burning:     $encp = $crypt->encrypt($text);

Comment: @Tinotenda I can't search for any native `encrypt()` function in the PHP docs (also i've never used it before.). I suppose you're using it as a plugin then?

Comment: ah, I see. I think the answer is in your plugin's docs/manuals. Maybe your custom class offers only encryption but not decryption (which would be really weird) just like http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_crypt.asp or you're using the wrong function to do it.